# How to make sure all columns are read as string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had thought this can make all values are read as string, but it doesn't:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', dtype=str, low_memory=False)
```

Because when I do this;

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     id_value = row['id']
     ...
```

My error message says that 'id_value' is a float, which can't do str concatenation.

Why can't dtype=str achieve that in dataframe?

Comment: Could the issue be that you have missing values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table) documentation, you have to set both `dtype=str` and `na_values=""`

> Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to preserve and not interpret dtype.

NaN is a float type (unless covering to the new pandas.NA), so if you have missing values, this is likely the origin of your error.

Also, I am not sure which operation you want to do, but if you make it vectorial (i.e. not using `iterrows`) this should handle the NaNs automatically.

Comment: id_value = row['id'] is a Nan value. how to check it's Nan. I want to remove all rows if id_value is Nan, because this property will be used as id. How to remove all rows which have row['id'] is Nan?

Comment: You could use `dropna` on your "id" column